# Unable to update the Dynamic form table in php

Tags: php

Generating a dynamic table from mysql Database and trying to update each row.

Snippet of dynamic table which was generated:

```
echo "<form id='contact' action='update.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table class='responstable'>";
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{ 
 $d=$row['Testcaseid'];
 $a=$row['Assignee'];
 $testcasename=$row['Testcasename'];
 $status=$row['Status'];
 $defectid=$row['Defect ID'];
 $executeddate=$row['Executed Date'];
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td><input  type='checkbox' value=$d></td>";
 echo "<td>$d</td><td name='Testcasename'>$testcasename</td>";
 echo "<td><input type='text' name='status' value='$status'>";
 echo "<td><input type='text'  name='assignee' style='width:125px;' 
 value=$a></input></td>";
 echo "<td><input name='defectid' value='$defectid'></input></td>";
 echo "<td><button type='Submit' name='submit' value='$d'>Update</button>
 </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";
```

The Update php Code:

```
 $Assignee = $_POST["assignee"];
 $Testcaseid= $_POST["submit"];
 $status=$_POST["status"];
 $defectid=$_POST["defectid"];
 $submit=$_POST["submit"];
 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The updated value given by  the user is not getting saved in the new variable in update, rather the value present in the db is getting stored.

How to  bring the user edit value in update.php?

Comment: What user edit value?

Comment: Value submitted in the form by a user

Comment: What value exactly? Or all of them? Either way, some error I can see: your checkbox doesn't have a name, enclose *all* attributes in quotes. In `update.php`: there is no field named `id` in your form, so `$_POST["id"]` will be empty

Comment: i have corrected it ,the problem iam facing is the value given for assignee or the status is not getting reflected in update.php.
$Assignee = $_POST["assignee"];
$Assignee is not storing the value which the user edits.

Comment: Could you please also update your above code to reflect the corrections you made? Thx. Are there actually values in your form for those two fields?

Comment: Yes values are already present in the form and the user tries to edit those.  need to save the user edited values back in db

Comment: You are assuming that the user enters values by "blindly" assigning the POST values in `update.php`. Since none of your fields have an attribute `required` users are able to submit empty values. Make sure the POST fields actually have a value before saving back to DB. You also failed to update your code with the corrections you made, so we are not working with the same code base. I'm out.

Comment: The issue iam facing here is the value edited by the user ,is not getting reflected in update.php.can some one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got Resolved when the form  is been given inside the while loop.